# How to evaluate the integral $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1}{1-a\cos t}dt, \text{ } a \in (0,1)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to prove the following equality:

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1}{1-a\cos t}dt = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-a^2}} \text{ , } a \in (0,1)$$

But I have gotten stuck with how to start. I thought about using the substitution $\cos t=\frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}$ but I didn't get very much with simplifying the integrand. I also tried multiplying by the conjugate to get $\frac{1+a\cos t}{1-a^2\cos^2t}$ as the integrand, but wasn't able to simplify this further into something integrable. I thought about differentiating each side but doing so would result in 0 on the RHS and no other substitution makes sense here.

Any suggestions how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prove $\int^{\pi}_{0} \frac{\cos nx}{1+\cos\alpha \cos x} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{\sin \alpha} (\tan \alpha - \sec \alpha)^n?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820446) (Your integral is twice that one, for $n=0$ and $\cos\alpha=-a$).

Comment: Do you know about complex integration?

Comment: You can use the so-called Weierstrass substitution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Comment: Yes, it is simpler than my first "duplicate", and the calculation is done in the middle of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4122847/386889) (for $t=-a$).

Comment: @Integralfan yes, this is for a complex analysis class. Would you suggest using residues here?

Comment: Yes, I'll write it up

Comment: @Integralfan Won't it be a duplicate of [the first](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1820526/386889) or [the second](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4122317/evaluating-an-integral-by-change-of-order-of-differentiation-and-integration/4122847#4122847) *spoilers* I mentionned above?

Comment: @MaxGertner Now you got these suggestions, better work on them than waiting to be spoon-fed, no?

Comment: @AnneBauval what do you think I'm currently doing?

Comment: Ok, fine. So I was wrong to worry about Itegral fan's last comment.

Comment: In fact, it has come out off by a sign error anyway and would only be true if $a \in (-1,0)$ instead. Sorry about this

Comment: [This duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4122847/386889) proves very simply (with Weierstrass substitution hinted above by Thomas Andrews) that$$\forall t\in(-1,1)\quad\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{dx}{1+t\cos x}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{1}{1-a \cos t} d t & =\int_{-\pi}^0 \frac{1}{1-a \cos t} d t+\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{1-a \cos t} d t \\
& \stackrel{t\mapsto \pi +t}{=}   \int_0^\pi \frac{1}{1+a \cos t} d t+\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{1-a \cos t} d t \\
& =-\int_0^\pi \frac{2}{1-a^2 \cos ^2 t} d t \\
& \stackrel{sym}{=}  4 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sec ^2 t}{\sec ^2 t-a^2} d t \\
& =4 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d(\tan t)}{1-a^2+\tan ^2 t} \\
& =\frac{4}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan t}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\right)\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \\
& =\frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{1-a^2}} \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$

Wish it helps.